# Get entities containing specific value - objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

In my google app application I have Entity with `public String[] UserRoles;` field. How can I fetch records that have some specific string in this list?

I mean, I'd like to write something like

```
ofy().load().type(ExampleEntity.class).filter("UserRoles contains", "foo").list()
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering in the datastore has special meaning for collection properties:

```
ofy().load().type(ExampleEntity.class).filter("UserRoles", "foo")
```

This means to load records which have "foo" as a value in the UserRoles collection (note that it's bad form in Java to have fields begin with capitals).

Make sure you @Index the field and your query should work.